# Mobius strip with constant negative curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, curvature, mobius-band

Is there any simple model of the Mobius strip with a constant negative Gaussian curvature? There is an example on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip#Open_M%C3%B6bius_band), but it only states that it can "easily" be seen that it is in fact homeomorphic to a Mobius strip, and I don't see it at all.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... take the band model ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_model ), cut out a rectangle (in a symmetric way), and glue the left and right edge with a twist, as usual.

Comment: Will the scalar product agree on the edges, though? It feels a bit too simple.

Comment: Alright, it seems it will, thank you so much :)